# What is your favorite free Netstat GUI / Connection Monitor app for Windows?

Tags: profiling, tcp, system-administration

I need something a little more feature rich than Sysinternals TCPView (which I regularly use) ... but it also must be freeware. :)

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what features you need?

Answer (score 4):

Well, the question is a bit old and I realize that probably you already found the software you were looking for... just in case, an interesting connection monitor utility is [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html), by Nir Sofer.

Freely adapted from the program's home page:

- displays the list of all currently opened TCP/IP and UDP ports on your local computer;
- for each port in the list, information about the process that opened the port is also displayed, including the process name, full path of the process, version information of the process (product name, file description, and so on), the time that the process was created, and the user that created it;
- allows you to close unwanted TCP connections, and kill the process that opened the ports;
- allows custom filters for inclusion/exclusion of connections.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a full blown traffic sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) will complement your tool set?

Amongst wiresharks features are:

- packet analysis
- traffic statistics
- capture
- coloring
- data export

Answer (score 0):

There's the [MS Network Monitor](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865).

Comment: Link redirects to the standard download center page. Any idea where this can be found now?

Comment: @stian; I updated the link with the new address.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [TCPView for Windows v2.53](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx).

[image http://i.technet.microsoft.com/bb897437.TcpView(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.technet.microsoft.com/bb897437.TcpView(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

TCPView is a Windows program that will show you detailed listings of all TCP and UDP endpoints on your system, including the local and remote addresses and state of TCP connections. On Windows Server 2008, Vista, NT, 2000 and XP TCPView also reports the name of the process that owns the endpoint. TCPView provides a more informative and conveniently presented subset of the Netstat program that ships with Windows. The TCPView download includes Tcpvcon, a command-line version with the same functionality.

Comment: -1; Bruno wants something other than TCPView, which he already uses.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what features you are looking for so this is my suggestion.

Without having used it, I have seen [TCPStat](http://www.mfcsnet.com/mfcstcpstat.htm) advertised a few times.
It looks like it was a discontinued project somewhere around 2003 and it's an awful blue color.

Answer (score 0):

Process Hacker shows also send/receive bytes, speed, country flag etc.